# Yellow Hot Dog Relish

Tags: sauce, hot-dog, ratio

I can not find my favourite hot dog relish sauce recipe but it included cucumbers, cabbage, peppers, and onions. I know it had tumeric as it was yellow but I am not sure of the ratio of vinegar to sugar. I think it used brown sugar. I also remember putting in a bag of spices that I removed after I had cooked the relish. So I would like to know what the best ratio of sugar to vinegar is as I don't want it too sweet and what spices and ratios should I use . 
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Caroline, welcome to this site. We don't do recipes here ([see the FAQ](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq)), so I propose you edit the question a bit. Your question(s) are valid.

Comment: You can discover your own personal 'best' ratio by adding sugar and vinegar little by little. First add the sugar and when it starts to become too much, add the vinegar. Weigh the sugar and vinegar before and after cooking, and you'll know how much you used.

Comment: http://www.cooks.com/rec/search/0,1-0,cucumber_hot_dog_relish,FF.html

Comment: I am considering closing this as a recipe request. While ratio questions are allowed, there is no optimal ratio in this case, as @BaffledCook mentioned, it is a matter of personal taste. Any thoughts for/against?

Comment: Do you mean [piccalilli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piccalilli)?

Comment: @rumtscho I suspect while there may not be a "one true ratio" for sugar:vinegar in hot dog relish, there is probably a fairly small range where the vast majority of recipes fall. That'd be a useful answer. So would BaffledCook's suggestion of how to find the right ratio.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is Chow-chow.  There are many variations but the basic seasoning are generally the same. There are recipes all over the web.